# Разложение в ряд Тейлора функции(Python). Приближённое значение функции

Tags: python, математика, ряды

Вроде бы ввожу правильное значение разложения в ряд Тейлора функции, а выдаёт не правильное значение. Подскажите, в чём проблема.

```
import math
from math import factorial
a=3.0
b=4.0
lich = 0
krok=(b-a)/10
lich=0

def f(x):
    return 1/(1+((math.e)**(1+x)))

def f_tochne(x, n):
    result=0
    for i in range(n):
        result += ((factorial(n))/((1+x)**n))
    return result
   
    

while a<=b:    
    print(round(a,2), end=' ')
    print(round(f(a),5),end=' ')
    print(round(f_tochne(a,lich),5))
    lich+=1
    a+=krok[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

[image: Разложение]

Comment: У вас во-первых неправильные записано пределы цикла, надо `range(n+1)`, во-вторых перепутан числитель со знаменателем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и без всяких импортов математики и факториалов...

```
def f(x):
    return 2.718281828459045**(1+x)

def tailor(x, eps):
    x = 1+x
    sum = 1+x
    term = x;
    n = 2;
    while term*term > eps*eps:
        term *= x/n
        n += 1
        sum += term
    return sum

a=3.0
b=4.0
krok=(b-a)/10

while a<=b:    
    print(round(a,2), end=' ')
    print(round(f(a),5),end=' ')
    print(round(tailor(a,1e-6),5))
    a+=krok
```

Как там таблицу выводить красиво - это я не очень знаю, Python - не мое, смотрите сами. Но вот так считать, не по количеству членов, а по заданной точности - оно как-то надежнее :) Кстати, пятью членами в этом диапазоне значений никак не отделаться - нужно штук 20...

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как именно разложить мою функцию в ряд Тейлора?

Comment: f(x)=1/(1+e**(1+x))

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0 - считайте производные, и вперед...

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import factorial


def taylor(x, n):
    return sum((1+x) ** i / factorial(i) for i in range(n + 1))
```

Comment: Постарайтесь дать более развернутый ответ

Comment: А что здесь объяснять? Базовые конструкции языка.